# Web XML and URL pattern mapping for servlets

Tags: servlets, httpserver

> I have a form action mapped to "loginURL" and my servlet url pattern
>   mapped as "/loginURL" However on click of submit, my application URL
>   has "/login". Why? And i get a 404 as expected.   I am learning HttpServlets and that is when I hit this issue.

```
Web.xml


<servlet>
  <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.learning.request.dispatch.LoginRequestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>loginServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/loginURL</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet>
```

HTML Form

```
<form action="loginURL" method="post">
Name:<input type="text" name="userName"/><br/><br/>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"/><br/><br/>

<input type="submit" value="login"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes 404 will throw due to the incorrect syntax in web.xmI. Do check the syntax!

Comment: I did check.. there is no error in the syntax. I want to know how the URL is  appended with /login when I have not specified it anywhere